# Create role based only on instance with Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Is there an option to create roles that we can assign only to instances but not to the whole class? I want to define a role scoped to a resource instance:

```
user = User.find(2)
user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first
```

But I want to avoid defining roles scoped to a whole class:

```
user = User.find(3)
user.add_role :moderator, Forum
```

Is there any way to forbid the second choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea about what `Rolify` provides for that, but you always might use plain old good ruby [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) for that:

```
User.prepend(Module.new do
  def add_role(role, target)
    raise "Not allowed" if target.is_a?(Class)
    super(role, target)
  end
end)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. 
I created Module in the lib directory. User class prepends this module. Roles and its limitations are defined in config file.